# Binding errado no <option> do <select> ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor, binding

Quando eu dou um post no form para o `Controller`, o binding no `asp-for="VehiclePlate"` pega o `value` do `option` do `select` (`@vehicle.Category`). Porém, eu quero pegar o `text` do `option` do `select` (`@vehicle.Plate`) no `Controller`. Como eu faço isso?

Esse é o `select`:

```
@model Exam
...
<select asp-for="VehiclePlate" id="listVehicle" data-init-plugin="select2" style="width: 100%">
    @foreach (var vehicle in ViewBag.Vehicles)
    {
       <option value="@vehicle.Category">@vehicle.Plate</option>
    }
</select>
```

Esse é o `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Exam exam)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Você precisa da categoria por algum outro motivo na tela? Se não é só você atribuir a placa no value também... <option value="@vehicle.Plate">@vehicle.Plate</option>

Comment: É exatamente isso, eu preciso da categoria.

Comment: Você quer postar a categoria, e na controller recuperar o a placa ou você precisa da categoria por outras condições na view? posta a sua classe Exam na pergunta, ela é uma entidade ou viewmodel?

Comment: Eu preciso da placa selecionada no Controller. Quero que o binding ocorra com a placa e não com a categoria. Eu preciso da categoria pra mostrar  na View em determinado momento. E classe Exam é uma ViewModel.

Comment: O caminho mais fácil então é receber a categoria no post e na controller recuperar a placa por ela.

Comment: Não é possível pois uma categoria pode pertencer a mais de uma placa.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70630/discussion-between-leandro-angelo-and-perozzo).